# Background color not rendering properly outside of the viewport

Tags: javascript

Ok, this is a tricky one..

On my website, when I want to change the background color on scroll, the background doesn't render properly outside of the current viewport. To reproduce this, go to http://thierry.zweidesign.ch and change the background color on the body via the DevTools. It's exactely the same behaviour as changing the color on a scroll event.

So confused..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'properly', it is acting as I expect it to.

Comment: When I change the color and then scroll down, the background is not rendered everywhere. On the initial viewport, everything's ok, but not outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming from your use of `position: absolute` on the `.page` element. Trying adding the following to your `.page` style:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Using absolute positioning means that parent elements no longer recognize the dimensions of your element so the body doesn't actually extend past the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Please explain how it is not working. Adding this to the stylesheet solved the problem for me in Chrome, I was able to turn the entire background to red. Is this only occurring on a particular browser?

Comment: I changed the CSS (.page position is now relative and overflow on auto) and it's still the same behaviour (Chrome). Does it work when you try it now? Maybe you changed the CSS after scrolling down the first time and then it worked?

Comment: It's possible that I may not have understood the problem correctly. When I add `background-color: red` to the body using chromebug, the background colour turns to red for the entire page, but leaves the grid pattern. It seems a bit glitchy for some reason and takes a second to fill the screen. Another solution is to add the background-color to the `html` element instead and make the body have `background-color: transparent`. This seems a little more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to css :

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

I suspect that's result of the viewport not expanding to entire content size.